# If our eye lens and cornea were flat would we still receive the world upside down?

Tags: human-biology

Usually the effect of a pinhole (or camera obscura) and the lens of our eyes are creating the world upside down on our retina.

Now imagine the lens and cornea would be flat is the pinhole effect still capable of creating a reversed image or would our vision be total blurred because (parts of) objects  shining straight in the middle into our eye would not be reversed while parts above or beneath the middle would be reversed?

Comment: Is this question about visual-cognitive orientation or the physics of a lens focusing light? If it's the former, see this CogSci answer about how visual orientation is perceived relatively- https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/339

Comment: Cross-posted at Physics: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/337807/44126

Comment: The question is definitely more on-topic on Physics.SE